# I am looking for a way to use MySQL 8.0 on Amazon EC2?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I have installed MySQL 8.0 as below
However, Mysql requires a password.
I found the default initial password /var/log/mysqld.log but it seems not correct one.
/var/log/mysqld.log

I use Amazon linux 2

Install

```
$ sudo mysql80-community-source MySQL 8.0 Community enabled
$ sudo yum install mysql-community-server
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.26 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

```
$ systemctl start mysqld
Failed to start mysqld.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
See system logs and 'systemctl status mysqld.service' for details.
```

Checking Status

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo  systemctl status mysqld
● mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-10-06 11:32:29 JST; 10s ago
```

```
$ sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
2020-05-31T13:56:58.175675Z 1 [Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: ll!.iXg=K4Rr
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo  mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo  mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
```

I used this
" ll!.iXg=K4Rr"
But Access denied happnend

I tried this.

```
$ sudo yum remove mysql-community-server
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
No Match for argument: mysql-community-server
No Packages marked for removal

$sudo yum remove  mysql-server

$sudo yum install mysql-community-server

$sudo mysql_secure_installation -p'password'

$ systemctl start mysqld

$ sudo mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: What linux is that? Amazon Linux 2?

Comment: Yes I use Amazon Linux 2

Comment: I'm wondering if you should be doing `yum install mysql-community-server`, not `yum install mysql-server`

Comment: I reinstall community-server